# How to run a query and then display the results on the next page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a search query that is run when a user clicks the next button. This works perfectly when the query runs etc. The only thing is that when the user is taken to the next page, nothing is populated in the `panelGrid`. How can I overcome this ?

The controller:

`UserTableController` ( run after the next button is pressed )

```
private String search;

private List<Usertable> item; // No need for DataModel here.
public List<Usertable> getItem() {
    return item;
}

public String submit() {
    item = ejbFacade.searchByString(search);
    return "View.xhtml"; //change this !, testing only

}

public String getSearch() {
    return search;
}

public void setSearch(String search) {
    this.search = search;
}
```

The view:

```
                        <p:dataTable id="UserTableSearch" 

                                     widgetVar="UserTableSearch" 
                                     paginator="true" rows="10"
                                     value="#{usertableController.item}"
                                     var="item"
                                     emptyMessage="No details was found with given criteria">

                            <p:column id="username"   
                                      headerText="username"
                                      sortBy="username">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="username"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.username}"/>
                            </p:column>


                        </p:dataTable>
```

How can I use the information to then populate a panelGrid of datatable on the next page?

Comment: If you're absolutely positive that `item` contains the right data inside `submit()` method, then those facade and query codes are completely irrelevant. You would have had exactly the same problem when you hardcoded and manually filled a `new ArrayList<Item>()` inside `submit()` method, right? Now, coming back to the concrete problem, it'd be helpful if you show how exactly you're displaying it in the XHTML file. The mistake is over there.

Comment: @SessionScoped and how  would i use post construct ? thanks

Comment: And ok thanks i will look into that and i think i have found the issue, i am calling the wrong code to display, i will post it in a sec, how can i post the results from this list ?

Comment: Your question is confusing. I'm nowhere seeing a `panelGrid`, but only a `dataTable`. This carelessness is not really appreciated. Also, you have nowhere shown how you have registered `UserTableController` as a managed bean. Is it using `@ManagedBean` or `@Named`? Show the entire annotation. The potential mistake is there.

Comment: I took the liberty to remove all irrelevant JPA noise from the question. If your debugger confirms that `item` is filled with the right data, then all code related to obtaining that data is absolutely not relevant. That part has then already done its job. You should then just concentrate on the current unit of work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that has made things clear, i think before i was miss understanding JPA, i have found the issue but will need to ask a new question as it is not related to JPA at all, Thanks for your help and making it more clear for me !